# Sonata page URL

Tags: sonata

What is concept creating url / path for sonata page - I want create not hardcoded path in template. In doc https://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/master/doc/reference/twig_helpers.html  have

```
8.1. URL
Render a page url

{{ path(page) }} => /absolute/path/to/url

{{ path(page, {}, true) }} => ../relative/path/to/url

{{ url(page) }} => https://sonata-project.org/absolute/url/to/url

{{ url(page, {}, true) }} => //sonata-project.org/network/path/to/url
```

what is page ?

i try page id , slug get error.

Answer (score 0):

I have try it.

Variable page was not defined - so i think its just an example in sonata doc.

If you type in shell (symfony-root-folder)

```
 php bin/console debug:router
```

You will get a list of all defined routes in your app.

You can use any name from this list as parameter. Eg: {{ url('sonata_admin_dashboard')}}

... and will get the Path from this list as path or url: Eg. http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard

More Info:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/debug.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html